# XSLT to generate element cardinalities

Tags: xslt, cardinality

I'd like to discover the structure of an XML dataset, for which I there's no XML schema. As part of this discovery, I'd like to compute the minimum and maximum cardinalities (`minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`) of the dataset's elements. I've tried various tools for generating XML schemas from XML documents, but they don't generate `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`. However, I suspect doing so is feasible with XSLT (2.0+).

More concretely, let's say I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a/>
    <b>
        <c/>
    </b>
    <b/>
</root>
```

I'd like to be able to compute cardinalities in the form like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <b minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
        <c minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </b>
</root>
```

Children of root will always have the same maximum and minimum cardinality, so that part can be computed with something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="name()">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:variable name="cardinality" select="count(current-group())"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="minOccurs" select="$cardinality"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="maxOccurs" select="$cardinality"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I can't wrap my head around how to continue with cardinalities of grandchildren. I suspect this can be abstracted into a recursive `xsl:function`.

Any suggestions on how to proceed are welcome!

Comment: "*Children of root with always have the same maximum and minimum cardinality*" Why is that?

Comment: Since there's only one root element, then its children will have only one cardinality in a single XML document.

Comment: > I've tried various tools for generating XML schemas from XML documents < Have you tried "Oxygen -> generate XML? [Docu Oxygen](https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/18.0/ug-editor/topics/converting-between-schema-languages.html)

Comment: A child of root cannot be optional (i.e. have minOccurs="0")?

Comment: Yes, I've tried Oxygen's schema generation. It almost satisfies my use case.  It uses `maxOccurs="unbounded"` instead of a concrete number. Moreover, I'd like to be able to extend the schema generation to account only for non-empty elements.

Comment: A child of root can be optional, however, when you look at a single XML document (my use case), it will a single cardinality. It would be different if I tried to compute the cardinalities from multiple XML documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure 100% if this will suit your needs, but I came up with this XSLT. It works by grouping elements by their path names (For example "root/a/b")

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="parent_path" match="*" use="string-join(ancestor::*/name(), '/')" />
    <xsl:key name="full_path" match="*" use="string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(), '/')" />

    <xsl:template match="/*" priority="2">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:call-template name="element" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" name="element">
        <xsl:variable name="path" select="string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(), '/')" />
        <xsl:for-each-group select="key('parent_path', $path)" group-by="name()">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:variable name="counts" select="key('full_path', $path)/count(*[name() = name(current())])" />
                <xsl:variable name="min" select="min($counts)" />
                <xsl:variable name="max" select="max($counts)"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="minOccurs" select="if (not(contains($path, '/'))) then $max else $min"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="maxOccurs" select="$max"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML

```
<root>
    <a/>
    <b>
        <c/>
        <c/>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c/>
        <d>
            <e />
        </d>
        <g></g>
        <g></g>
        <g></g>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c/>
        <d>
            <e />
            <e />
        </d>
        <g></g>
        <g></g>
    </b>
    <a/>
</root>
```

The following is output....

```
<root>
   <a minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2"/>
   <b minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="3">
      <c minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
      <d minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
         <e minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
      </d>
      <g minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3"/>
   </b>
</root>
```

Comment: The minimum cardinality is not computed correctly. If I understand `if (not(contains($path, '/'))) then $cardinality else 0` correctly, then all elements with a non-root parent will have the minimal cardinality set 0, while the others will have the same minimum and maximum cardinality.

Comment: Sorry, I made the assumption than non-root elements always needs a minOccurs of 0. However, I've made a tweak to my answer so now it should calculate the minimum based on the minimum number of child elements rather than assume a 0.